# Adding WHERE clause to outer query causes inner query to error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below query worked until I added a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    PersonTable.FullName,
    View_PersonToHead.DirectorId
FROM PersonTable
LEFT JOIN View_PersonToDirector ON PersonTable.PersonId = View_PersonToDirector.PersonId
WHERE View_PersonToDirector.DirectorId = 12345 --No error if this line is removed
```

The error message is:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

This leads me to believe that there was an error with how I wrote the `View_PersonToDirector` view. Something about adding the WHERE clause causes the query to be evaluated/optimized in a different way, exposing some issue.

Internals of `View_PersonToDirector`:

```
WITH items AS (
    SELECT
        PersonId,
        0 AS [Level],
        CAST(PersonId AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [Path]
    FROM PersonTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        e.PersonId,
        [Level] + 1,
        CAST([Path] + ' < ' + CAST(e.PersonId AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
    FROM PersonTable e
    INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.PersonId = e.ManagerId
)

SELECT
    A.PersonId,
    CASE
        WHEN A.[Level] = 1
        THEN A.PersonId
        ELSE CAST(LEFT(A.PathToDirector, CHARINDEX(' ', A.PathToDirector)) AS INT)
    END AS DirectorId
FROM (
    SELECT
        items.PersonId,
        items.[Level],
        RIGHT(items.[Path], LEN(items.[Path])-7) AS PathToDirector
    FROM items

    WHERE Path LIKE '1111 < %' --Id of director
) A
```

I suspect that having a WITH cte in the view causes the query optimizer to work differently, applying the WHERE filtering in a different order. Is this bad practice?

Comment: `LEN(items.[Path])-7` becomes zero or negative at some point. I suppose the path would look like `1234` for top level person which fails the len - 7.

Comment: Also, tell us what happens when you SELECT * FROM View_PersonToDirector WHERE View_PersonToDirector.DirectorId = 12345

Lastly, would it be too much to use aliases in the future?   It might help on readability.   Not a deal breaker though.

Comment: @Salman A, That's what I first looked at, but those cases should be eliminated by the second-to-last line: WHERE Path LIKE '1111 < %'.

Comment: @TinyHaitian, that case results in the same error.

Comment: @user7733611 no, SQL Server decides when to evaluate the WHERE clause. And your where clause is kind of recursive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is definitely in this code:

```
RIGHT(items.[Path], LEN(items.[Path])-7) AS PathToDirector
```

I *appreciate* that you think that this `WHERE` clause fixes the problem:

```
WHERE Path LIKE '1111 < %'
```

But it does not.  The problem is that SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  This true even for subqueries, CTEs, and views.  These can be evaluated in any order.  In fact, SQL Server sometimes pushes the evaluation to the node that reads from the table -- which is why you get an error.

Personally, I think this is a bug in SQL Server.  Those powers that be do not agree.  Here are two solutions:

```
(CASE WHEN Path LIKE '1111 < %' THEN RIGHT(items.[Path], LEN(items.[Path])-7) END) AS PathToDirector
```

Or:

```
(CASE WHEN Path LIKE '1111 < %' THEN RIGHT(items.[Path], LEN(items.[Path] + '1234567')-7) END AS PathToDirector
```

You may have the same problem with the `CHARINDEX()`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a where condition related  to column from left join table generate and implicit inner join
In this case add  the condition to the ON clause for let the left join work

```
SELECT
  PersonTable.FullName,
  View_PersonToHead.DirectorId
FROM PersonTable
LEFT JOIN View_PersonToDirector ON PersonTable.PersonId = View_PersonToDirector.PersonId
   AND  View_PersonToDirector.DirectorId = 12345
```

for the length problem try use conditional eg using case

```
SELECT
    items.PersonId,
    items.[Level],
    case when LEN(items.[Path]) > 7 then  RIGHT(items.[Path], LEN(items.[Path])-7) 
       ELSE items.[Path] END AS PathToDirector
FROM items
```

Comment: Yeah, this results in the same problem. I could have also written this with an inner join, with both conditions in the ON.

Comment: answer  updated ..  for the length problem ..hope is useful

Answer (score 1):

The base part of your rCTE has:

```
CAST(PersonId AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [Path]
```

Which means base rows of the rCTE would contain values such as `1234` which are shorter than 7 characters and cause `RIGHT(x, LEN(x) - 7)` to fail. The condition:

```
RIGHT(items.[Path], LEN(items.[Path])-7) AS PathToDirector
```

Could be safely written as:

```
SUBSTRING(items.[Path], NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' < ', items.[Path]), 0) + 3, LEN(items.[Path]))
```